# Java Coordinate Point

Tags: java

> Write a program that will have a method called coordinate_point that will take any two 
>   integers and display its form of (x,y) where x and y are the any 2 integers being passed.

I have no idea why I'm having trouble with this because it seems like beginners work...but I don't even know where to begin. How do I display 2 integers with a , in between like a location point?

Comment: I guess it means as a string.

Comment: Java or JavaScript? There are completely different languages.

Comment: Java is to JavaScript as car is to carpet. Which are you using, Java or JavaScript?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: You probably want to return a string in the format of (x,y). Assuming you're talking about Java, check out the String.format() method.

Comment: @andrewap The description doesn't say to return a String. It says to "display". If this is Java, a short SOP will do the trick.

Comment: Yeah Andrew...thats exactly what I need.

Comment: `System.out.println("(" + x + "," + y + ")");`

Comment: @Code-Guru You're right. I was mainly focusing on using String.format() method as an alternative to the + operator for formatting the output.

Answer (score 2):

```
String display = "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
System.out.println("Display = " + display);
```